# C Unions with Files and buffer overflow?

Tags: c, unions

My program loads/saves `double` value into a text file using union.

I think I am having a buffer overflow, when I use `fflush(stdin)` it works, but I can't. The problem maybe somewhere else though. The code jumps without letting me enter a file to load from ( 2.000000 is autoinserted ).

Ps. Yes I know that tab[i] would be better than *(tab+i) but spare me, I just have to do it like this.

output :

```
Enter double value:8794.061758
 Enter path to file you wish to save:valleykingstopwantreachspellshipcontinue
File saved
Enter a path to file you wish to load: 2.000000   ----- This value is inserted automatically ( I didnt write it)
Process finished with exit code 0
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

union double_to_char_t
{
    double d;
    char bytes[8];
};

int save_double(const union double_to_char_t *dtc, const char *filename)
{
    if(dtc == NULL || filename == NULL) return 1;

    FILE * f=fopen(filename,"w");
    if(f == NULL) return 2;

    int result = fwrite(dtc, sizeof(dtc), 1, f);
    if( result != 1)
        {
            fclose(f);
            return 3;
        }

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}

int load_double(union double_to_char_t *dtc, const char *filename)
{
    if( dtc == NULL || filename == NULL) return 1;

    FILE * f = fopen(filename,"r");
    if( f == NULL ) return 2;

    int result = fread(dtc, sizeof(dtc), 1, f);
        if( result != 1)
        {
            fclose(f);
            return 3;
        }

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    union double_to_char_t unia;
    char temp1[40] = {0};
    char temp2[40] = {0};
    char *input1 = temp1;
    char *input2 = temp2;

    printf("Enter double value: ");
    if(scanf(" %lf",&(unia.d))!=1)
    {
        printf("Incorrect input");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter path to file you wish to save:");
    fgets(input1, 40, stdin);

    int wynik = save_double(&unia,input1);
    if(wynik > 0)
    {
        printf("Couldn't create file\n");
        exit(5);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File saved\n");
    }
    printf("Enter a path to file you wish to load: ");
    fgets(input2, 40, stdin);
    // scanf(" %39[^\n]", input2);

    int score = load_double(&unia,input2);
    if(score > 0 && score < 3)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open file\n");
        exit(4);
    }
    if(score == 3)
    {
        printf("File corrupted\n");
        exit(6);
    }
    printf("%f",unia.d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is not standard C, it's a Microsoft extension.

Comment: Why are you using a loop? Why not just `fwrite(dtc, sizeof(dtc), 1, f);`?

Comment: Don't use `scanf()` to read input lines. Use `fgets()` to read a line, then you can use `sscanf()` to parse it.

Comment: regarding: `fgets(input1, 40, stdin);`  do not assume that the call to `fgets()` was successful.  Rather  check the returned value for not NULL.  I.E.   `if( ! fgets(input1, 40, stdin) ) { perror( "fgets failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: regarding: `if(scanf(" %lf",&(unia.d))!=1)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for double from user failed\n" );
        exit(1);
    }
    
    printf("Enter path to file you wish to save:");
    fgets(input1, 40, stdin);`  the call to `scanf()` leaves the newline in the `stdin` buffer.  Then the call to `fgets()` encounters the newline and immediately returns.  The code needs to clear `stdin` after the call to `scanf()`  Suggest: `int ch; while( (ch = getchar() ) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}`

Comment: regarding: `#include <string.h>`  it is a poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.  Suggest removing that statement

Comment: regarding: `int load_double(union double_to_char_t *dtc, const char *filename) {     if( dtc == NULL || filename == NULL) return 1;      FILE * f = fopen(filename,"r");     if( f == NULL ) return 2;      int result = fread(dtc, sizeof(dtc), 1, f);` 1) the sizeof( dtc ) will result in the size of a pointer, not the size of the union: `double_to_char_t` 2) the function: `fread()` returns a `size_t`, not a `int`. suggest: `size_t result = fread(dtc, sizeof( union double_to_char_t ), 1, f);`

Answer (score 1):

You used `%39[^\n]` to read the filename, then typed a 40 character filename. The first 39 characters were put into `input1`, and the last character was left in the input stream.

When you then tried to get the filename for `input2`, it read that last character. That's why it didn't wait for you to type anything -- there was still input available after the first filename was read.

So you saved to `valleykingstopwantreachspellshipcontinu` and loaded from `e`.

You need to ensure that your input buffer is longer than any potential input. If you use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`, you can test whether the input ends with a newline. If not, you can report that the input was too long, read characters until the newline, then ask for input again. (The non-standard `fflush(stdin)` discards everything up to the next newline, which is why adding that fixed the problem.)

```
if (!fgets(input1, 40, stdin)) {
    printf("input error\n");
    exit(1);
}
if (input1[strlen(input1)-1] != '\n') { // check for trailing newline
    printf("filename too long\n);
    exit(3);
}
input1[strlen(input1)-1] = '\0'; // remove it before using as filename
```

You could also use the `getline()` function. This isn't standard C, but it's POSIX and widely implemented. It allocates the input buffer dynamically so any length can be accomodated.

Comment: You mean like this ? ````fgets(input1, 40, stdin);```` This didnt work, and should i change first scanf to something or not? Can I use fgets for union aswell ? Can you show please

Comment: regarding `if(f == NULL) return 2;` and similar statements:  when an error occurs, always inform the user.  When the error is from a C library function call `perror( "fopen failed" )'` which will output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.   For other errors (like) `if(dtc == NULL || filename == NULL) return 1;` use: `fprintf( stderr, "your error message\n" );`  which will output your error message to `stderr`

Comment: regarding:  `fgets(input1, 40, stdin);` in `main()`:  always remove any (possible) trailing newline.  Suggest: `input1[ strcspn( input1, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: @Simonsoft177 I've updated the answer to show how to do this

Comment: Note: the `scanf()`  family of functions are 'successful' if they return a number less than the expected number of 'input format conversion' specifiers. so must use the `fprintf( stderr, ...)` method of informing the user of the error